# How to exit script if external call exceeds time limit

Tags: php, bash, configuration

PHP Has a method called set_time_limit (and a config option max_execution_time), which allows you to specify a time limit which triggers the script to exit when reached. However, this does not take into account time on external calls. Which means that if (for example) the PHP script makes a database call that does something dumb and runs for hours, the set time limit will not trigger.

If I want to guarantee that my PHP script's execution time will not exceed a specific time, is there some way to do this? I'm running the script directly in PHP (rather than via apache or similar), so I'm considering writing a bash script to monitor ps and kill it after a certain time. It occurs to me that I can't be the first person with this problem though, so is there some already-built solution available for this?

Note: This question is NOT about the PHP error from exceeding it's maxed execution time. This is about the case where PHP exceeds a time limit *without* triggering this error. This question is NOT just about limiting the time of a PHP script, it is about limiting the time allowed to a PHP script *making external calls*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running PHP from the command line the default setting "max_execution_time" is 0.
You can try something similar to solve your problem.

```
$cmd = "(sleep 10  && kill -9 ".getmypid().") > /dev/null &";
exec($cmd); //issue a command to force kill this process in 10 seconds

$i=0;
while(1){
    echo $i++."\n";
    sleep(1); //simulating a query
}
```